# Pyinstaller Maximum Recursion Depth Exceded

Tags: pandas, pyinstaller, openpyxl

I am trying to create an executable from python 3.6.4 using pyinstaller 3.3.1. The packages I am using are Pandas and openpyxl. When I try to create the bundle I receive this error.

`$ RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`

I have tried increasing my recursion limit and most of the steps described in How to Report Bugs and the error is still the same. I also got the same error when I tried bundling

```
import openpyxl
print("Hello World")
```

so I think the problem has to do with openpyxl but pyinstaller is supposed to be compatible with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Install the development version, it should have been resolved in [#2919](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2919):

```
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/tarball/develop
```

Comment: I'm using python3.6.4, and I installed pyinstaller using the development version (see above) for PyInstaller-3.4.dev0+bb5d04ef8, and I receive the recursion error.  Should I use an earlier version of Python 3?  Python 3.5?

Comment: To me, only python 3.5.2 worked. 3.5.3 or 3.6 didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the build & dist folder, and try run your pyinstaller yourscript.py again.
For my case, python 3.6.3 version still be able to run it.