# Pyinstaller development version: recursion depth reached

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

With due reference to question at [Pyinstaller Maximum Recursion Depth Exceded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48894407/pyinstaller-maximum-recursion-depth-exceded), I removed all versions of pyinstaller and associated folders.  I installed the newest development version of pyinstaller with:

```
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/tarball/develop
```

Using pyinstaller still causes this error message:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded.
```

I am using Python 3.6.4.  I've seen that others downgrade to Python 3.5.  Others suggest increasing the recursion depth in the spec file (http://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html).

Can anyone suggest the best path forward?

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I ripped out Python 3.6.4 and installed Python 3.5.2.  Now, pyinstaller and P3.5.2 play well together.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can increase the recursion limit by adding the following to the beginning of the .spec file:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)
```